# GUI auto layout using Swing or Java-FX

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am thinking to build a GUI using Java Sswing since Java-FX is not supported in RedHat 5.x meaning I have to use something more general. Is there a way that I can do auto-layout in Swing? For example, the top menu bars and the dropdown items per bar are given by the server instead of hard-coded in the client. If Swing doesn't have it, does Java-FX have this functionality?

Comment: *"For example, the top menu bars and the dropdown items per bar are given by the server.."* What 'server'?

Comment: You use the term "auto-layout".  Are you referring to the IOS "Auto Layout"?  As UI frameworks should, both Swing and JavaFX have the concept of layout managers.  For Swing see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  There is also FormLaout and MigLayout.  All depends on what you need.  And none of it requires a server(?).

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can do it in JavaFX and in Swing with similar effort.

**JavaFX** (considering an SQL server) you can always add elements as you get them, below is an example of filling a *ComboBox*, but it would be really similar with **MenuButton** (you would just have to create the **MenuItems** before).

```
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_table");
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        while(results.next()){
            cb.getItems().add(results.getString("test_col"));
        }
```

**Swing**

```
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_table");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        while(results.next()){
            buttonPanel.add(new JButton(results.getString("test_col")));
        }
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
```